# Need SQL query to return different data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a spreadsheet with 1256 records that need to be updated. Basically, it is a number of records I need to join to a customObject table. I need to update any of the records that have objectNumber = 6 and if it does not have objectNumber 6 I must create these records.

When I search for the 1256 records in the database, 976 are returned meaning 280 records do NOT have 'objectNumber' 6.

I find the records with objectNumber 6 using the following query:

```
SELECT 
  a.column1, 
  a.column2, 
  a.objectNumber, 
  b.customcolumn
  b.column2
FROM table1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.column2 = b.column2
WHERE a.column1 IN (<my list of 1256 Ids go here>)
  AND a.objectNumber = 6
```

I want to return the 280 records that do NOT have object Number 6. The problem with changing my last line of the query to `AND a.objectNumber <> 6` means I return all of the records that have object number 1, 2, 3, 4 etc and returns over 3000 rows.

Comment: Wouldn't the result without the `AND a.objectNumber = 6` return the 1256 records? Also, what do you mean by **not have 'objectNumber' 6**? Is the cell **null**? *(To try to find the 280 records of nots, reaching the 1256 records that make the total would help.)*

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple rows in `a` or `b` that have the same value in column2? If there are, the query will return one row for each valid combination of the a and b tables.

Comment: I guess what you want is `LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.column2 = b.column2 AND a.objectNumber = 6`

Comment: The extra rows are being returned because of the INNER JOIN.  It finds all of the records with objectNumber = 6 and then finds EVERY occurrence where table1.column2 = table2.column2.  In this case, a single row could return a thousand results, depending on what's in table2

Comment: hey @Edu, thank you for your reply.

I was not very clear. Because there are objectNUmbers 1,2,3,4 etc etc, my query is specifically asking for objectNumber 6... Object number 6 is then joined so that I can view a text field (b.customcolumn) which I am then required to update.... Without a.objectNumber = 6, it returns 3125 rows (with my 1256 IDs in 'WHERE a.column1 IN (....') as it is returning all the other objects if you get me...

By not having 'objectNumber6' I mean that there are rows there but they have objectnumber 1,2,3 etc and I need to insert 6 if that makes sense

Comment: You really need to post some sample data here and some expected results.  It's not at all clear what you're looking for based on your description.

Comment: Slightly off topic but far too often I see NOLOCK used when the person really does not understand all the things that hint brings to the table. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: If you don't use the `table2`, there're 976 rows having 6 and 280 rows having other values. So the additional rows are joined by using INNER JOIN to the `table2`. It means `table2.column2` have multiple matches to `table1.column2` for a given value.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what's available to search on but it seems that objectNumber is an integer and can have 1,2,3,4, etc, or 6 as a value. If, in "etc" you mean NULL or '' (''being a "blank") then you can try this:

--if NULL or '' is an option:

> and (a.objectNumber is NULL or a.objectNumber = '')

--if the 280 records you are trying to update to 6 have a known value then you can eliminate that/those values:

> and a.objectNumber not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,*or whatever value*)